# Question on SQL Server 2008 R2 Web with 1 processor MOLP

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows

My client are considering getting the above mentioned SQL server license but I have no idea of what MOLP is actually. Before I say "OK, go ahead" to them, I want to know something:

- Is the SQL Server Management same as Standard edition?
- Does it allow hundreds or thousand of users to make to connection to it?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> •Is the SQL Server Management same as Standard edition?

Yes

> •Does it allow hundreds or thousand of users to make to connection to
>   it?

If you give it enough ram and program stupid enough that t his is needed, yes. Normally it is not needed - a connection shoudl be reused and only be open during processing, and there is no way you process thousands of pages at the same time. If you open connections ad paage start, close them at th end you  will use only very few connections for thousands of users.

That said, performance may be an issue. Make sure you buy HARDWARE suiteable for your load.

And your client should consider RENTING using SPLA. A lot cheaper, monthly scalable and never pay for updates.

Comment: Good points! To clarify SPLA, smaller investment although more expensive over time.

Comment: I understand the benefit of SPLA, but that is out of my hand since their supplier only provide them the MOLP. @TomTom, basically there might be more than one user session for the web application, each user session will have its own db connection. From what you mean, I supposed this is possible for 1-Processor MOLP right?

Comment: Yes, but i would fire every programmer doing that. Teying db connectiosn to user sessions is one thing - utterly stupid. Immediate termination without notice incompetence. Sessions should NOT contain databae connections. And, their supplier CAN NOT supply them with SPLA - they have to contact a SPLA partner and sign a contract there. Takes an hour. SAVES over time (sorry, 3molo) due to scalaiblity and no updates needed.